# Disable image processing

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

How can i disable the processing of images while element is being saved? when i edit the html of a text-element and add an image with a relative path, the editor creates an absolute path and furthermore processes the image. the image is copied to a new folder and the src-path is adjusted. i want to get rid of this behaviour. it this possible, so i can just set the src-attribute of the image and it will stay like that?

I'm using the extension "TinyMCE".

Comment: In the install tool, under "All configuration" in the "GFX" section, you can disable **all** image processing (first setting there). Not sure if that is what you really want...

Comment: i saw that, too. but i guess i need more an option that my image attributes are not touched at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the TCA of your extension, remove the configuration parameter 'uploadfolder'. This will lead to the behaviour that the file is referenced to the original location instead of being copied. See the [TCA reference](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Group/Index.html#uploadfolder) for more information.

The configuration might look like this:

```
    'image' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_yourextension_domain_model_yourmodel.image',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 1,
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'disallowed' => '',
            // removing/commentingthe next line will create a reference instead of copying the file
            // 'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_yourextension', // 
        ),
    ),
```